# What is the Search Companies tab ordering its searches by?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am wandering through the ["Search Companies"](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) tab and looking for companies that offer remote positions. That returns [129 results](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?searchTerm=&location=&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles&allowsremote=true).

These results don't appear to always be in the same order. Additionally, if I page through the results, I see the same company across multiple pages.

What is this tab ordering its searches by and should the same company appear on multiple pages?

Some companies that I noticed were duplicated on my results:

- EVIL STUDIOS on pages 1 and 3
- Olo on pages 1 and 3
- Compose on pages 2 and 3
- Forty Two Ltd on pages 1 and 2
- Keen.io on pages 1 and 4

Comment: What companies are repeated?

Comment: @DeanWard, I added some of the duplicates I noticed.

Comment: thanks, looking into it. Looks like the sorting isn't consistently doing the right thing in Elastic :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug crept in during a recent refactor. We inadvertently specified a weighting algorithm for company search that didn't take into account anything other than the time a company last posted a job. As a result a lot of companies ended up with exactly the same weight and Elastic ordered them in a seemingly random fashion.

I've just pushed a build to prod that fixes the issue.

Thanks for the report!